# Why do I get a result before submit button?

Tags: php

I'm trying to run this little block of code, but I get the message "Please check all fields" even before hitting the submit button. Why is this happening? Do I need to clear the cache?

```
<form name="frm1" action="index3.php" method="POST">
question 1:<br>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="1" /> Answer 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="2" /> Answer 2<br>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="3" /> Answer 3<br><br>
question 2:<br>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="1" /> Answer 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="2" /> Answer 2<br>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="3" /> Answer 3<br><br>
question 3:<br>
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="1" /> Answer 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="2" /> Answer 2<br>
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="3" /> Answer 3<br> <br>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit Form" />
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['q1']) && isset($_POST['q2']) && isset($_POST['q3'])) {

        $q1 = $_POST['q1'];
        if ($q1 == 1) {$q1a = "Blank Answer A";} ;
        if ($q1 == 2) {$q1a = "Blank Answer B";} ;
        if ($q1 == 3) {$q1a = "Blank Answer C";} ;
        echo $q1a;
        echo '<br>';

        $q2 = $_POST['q2'];
        if ($q2 == 1) {$q2a = "Blank Answer A";} ;
        if ($q2 == 2) {$q2a = "Blank Answer B";} ;
        if ($q2 == 3) {$q2a = "Blank Answer C";} ;
        echo $q2a;
        echo '<br>';

        $q3 = $_POST['q3'];
        if ($q3 == 1) {$q3a = "Blank Answer A";} ;
        if ($q3 == 2) {$q3a = "Blank Answer B";} ;
        if ($q3 == 3) {$q3a = "Blank Answer C";} ;
        echo $q3a;
        echo '<br>';                

        } else { 
        echo "Please check all fields"; 

}
?>
```

Comment: Because you haven't POSTed your form, yet... _(according to your `if-else` statement... :)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it this way:

```
//check if submit button has been clicked
if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])){

  if(isset($_POST['q1']) && isset($_POST['q2']) && isset($_POST['q3'])) {

        $q1 = $_POST['q1'];
        if ($q1 == 1) {$q1a = "Blank Answer A";} ;
        if ($q1 == 2) {$q1a = "Blank Answer B";} ;
        if ($q1 == 3) {$q1a = "Blank Answer C";} ;
        echo $q1a;
        echo '<br>';

        $q2 = $_POST['q2'];
        if ($q2 == 1) {$q2a = "Blank Answer A";} ;
        if ($q2 == 2) {$q2a = "Blank Answer B";} ;
        if ($q2 == 3) {$q2a = "Blank Answer C";} ;
        echo $q2a;
        echo '<br>';

        $q3 = $_POST['q3'];
        if ($q3 == 1) {$q3a = "Blank Answer A";} ;
        if ($q3 == 2) {$q3a = "Blank Answer B";} ;
        if ($q3 == 3) {$q3a = "Blank Answer C";} ;
        echo $q3a;
        echo '<br>';                

   } else { 
     echo "Please check all fields"; 
   }
}
```

Comment: small typo there, but it worked! Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
if(isset($_POST['q1']) && isset($_POST['q2']) && isset($_POST['q3'])) {
  ... 
}
else {
  ...
}
```

with

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  if(isset($_POST['q1']) && isset($_POST['q2']) && isset($_POST['q3'])) {
    ... 
  }
  else {
    ...
  }
}
```

This way the error message will not appear unless some data was posted.

Comment: isn't `$_POST` always set? Just set to an empty array if no post data. I generally check for `if(!empty($_POST)){...`

Comment: I think that if the request was not made through post, then it would not be set, anyway your solutions would be ok too.

Comment: That would make sense. However that's not the way it works: http://codepad.viper-7.com/wYE8QV

Comment: Going for `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` then!